# Qt dragging item at scene position while moving

Tags: qt, events, qt4, pyqt, pyside

Dragging qgraphicsitem around scene can be done in several ways. But the most interesting to me is with attaching flag "itemIsMovable" cause it should be more "native" with Qt library.

My question is; while item is dragging what should be way to print it's position? Remember, we have already flag, the item is moving and position is returning somewhere.

Down is the example. Problem is how to interactively update connected line between rectangle and circle (use toolbar icon to add circle with connected line).

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class drawCircle(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, scene):
        self.Circle = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(-20, -20, 40, 40)
        self.Circle.setPos(50,50)
        self.Circle.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        scene.addItem(self.Circle)

        self.Line = QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem(-20, -20, 40, 40)
        self.Line.setLine(0, 0, self.Circle.pos().x(), self.Circle.pos().y())
        scene.addItem(self.Line)

class winScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(winScene, self).__init__()
        self.setSceneRect(0,0,450,200)
        self.addItem(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(-20, -20, 40, 40))

class SceneWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SceneWindow, self).__init__()
        self.DefineSceneWindow()

    def DefineSceneWindow(self):
        self.SchSc = winScene()
        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.SchSc)
        view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        view.scale(1,1)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.setGeometry(0, 300, 500, 300)
        self.show()

        self.drRect = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('paint_brush.png'), 'Draw Circle', self)
        self.drRect.setShortcut('Ctrl+R')
        self.drRect.triggered.connect(self.DefineAction)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('tools')
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.drRect)

    def DefineAction(self):
        drawCircle(self.SchSc)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SceneWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reimplement `QGraphicsItem.itemChange(change, value)` to detect scene position changes.  The PySide [docs](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsItem.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsItem.itemChange) have a directly related example.

Comment: So, what should be the less expensive way in dragging item: this one with flag attached ItemSendsScenePositionChanges or by item.grabMouse attaching interactively at scene event def (having in mind that should be lot of demanding items and groups)?

Comment: From the `QGraphicsItem::grabMouse()` docs: "It is almost never necessary to explicitly grab the mouse in Qt".  Use what I suggested to be notified of scene position changes.

Comment: @Alex SO isn't that kind of site.  The closest equivalent would be to create a new room in chat.